# can not understand how pairs in c++ stl work?

Tags: c++, stl

While reading a tutorial on Topcoder I came across a statement

> Pairs are compared first-to-second element. If the first elements are not equal, the result will be based on the comparison of the first elements only; the second elements will be compared only if the first ones are equal.

I cannot understand what this statement is trying to say?

Comment: They are compared lexicographically.

Comment: Lexicographically: means they are compared like the names in a telephone book.

Comment: If you think about how decimal numbers are compared the *most significant digit* always has total precedence over all the digits of *lesser significance*. So unless the hundreds columns are equal between two numbers you don't even bother to look at the tens or the units. But if the hundreds columns are equal, then you go check the tens column. With a `std::pair` you only have two 'columns': `std::pair::first` and `std::pair::second`. Unless the first columns (`std::pair::first`) are equal, no need to bother checking the second (`std::pair::second`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider pairs of `std::pair<int, int>`

```
std::pair<int, int> a = {1,1};
std::pair<int, int> b = {1,3};
std::pair<int, int> c = {3,2};
```

To determine `a < c` we can look at the first item and see that `1 < 3`. We don't even need to consider the second element at this point.

But to determine `a < b`, both first items are `1`, so we must then look at the second item to see that `1 < 3`.

If you compare `b < c`, you will find that `b` has a smaller 1st element, but `c` has a smaller second element. Since the first element takes precedence, it `b` will be considered smaller.

So if you were to sort these pairs, they would be arranged

```
a < b < c
```

Answer (score 1):

It means the following expression

```
( p1.first == p2.first ) && ( p1.second == p2.second )
```

If subexpression

```
( p1.first == p2.first )
```

is equal to `flase` then subexpression

```
( p1.second == p2.second )
```

will not be evaluated because it is already clear that the whole expression will be equal to `false`.

That is the comparison of pairs corresponds to evaluation of logical AND operator that according to the C++ STandard evaluates the following way

> 1 The && operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). The result is true if both
>   operands are true and false otherwise. Unlike &, && guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation: **the second operand is not evaluated if the
>   first operand is false.**

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have list of names of persons which you want to sort alphabatically. Assume also that every name has `first name` and `last name` only.

How would you sort?

You just compare first names until they match exactly. When first names are same then you check for second name.

Comment: Most name lists (in America?) sort by last name, then first name, which is unlike pair which compares first then last